# Tests and code-coverage with private methods with Angular and Jasmine/Karma

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, code-coverage, karma-coverage

So, I got these methods on my button component.

```
export class SidebarButtonComponent implements OnInit {

  private subscribeToRouter(): void {
    this.router.events.subscribe(route => {
      if (route instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.isSelected(route.urlAfterRedirects);
      }
    });
  }

  private isSelected(route: string): void {
    if (this.checkRoute(route)) {
      this.selected = true;
    } else {
      this.selected = false;
    }
  }

  private checkRoute(route: string): boolean {
    return route.includes(this.link);
  }

}
```

I know I can't access private methods on my specs files, but the code coverage from Angular says I don't cover it:

[59.09% Statements 13/22 37.5% Branches 3/8 42.86% Functions 3/7 52.63% Lines 10/19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSqoq.png)

What's the best methods to test these private tests, or at least, ignore them in code coverage?

Comment: There should be some public method in your component that calls private functions, in that case you can write UT of public method with all possible combinations so that it covers private method as well and you will get coverage of private methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access modifiers in typescript are only used in compile time. You can't directly access them like this

```
component.privateMethod(); // not accessible
```

But you can access them using any:

```
(component as any).privateMethod();
```

This is a workaround to access the private methods, otherwise you can test them using the methods in which these private methods are called.